# Xamarin.Build.Download.targets - invalid Id

Tags: xamarin, build

I cannot build the project after adding Xamarin.Firebase.Functions nuget (v120.0.0) . The error message is:

```
Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(3,3): Error XBD020: Invalid item ID firebaseappcheckinterop-16.0.0-beta01
```

What can it be? I already tried the usual things like deleting the bin/obj folders, rebuilding, restarting, installing different versions of Xamarin.Build.Download. No idea where to even start investigating this issue.

Comment: I download `Xamarin.Firebase.Functions nuget (v120.0.0)` on Xamarin.Android project, and also having this error message, and I don't find any helpful info, so suggest you can feedback this question at [Xamarin Google github](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues)

Comment: I did, no answer yet. Though it seems to work with v119.2.0, give it a try.

Comment: If you have any update, please share it here, and also feedback problem at 
[GooglePlayServicesComponents](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is happening due to the Xamarin.Build.Download package doing some aggressive package id format checking. It doesn't like that `-beta01` postfix.

More details at the issue I opened on GitHub: https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/issues/1293

For an immediate solution, I suggest either:

- Downgrade to a version of Xamarin.Firebase.Functions that does not include a preview package as a transitive dependency
- Fork the XamarinComponents repo and remove or modify the id check (as detailed in the above linked github issue). Ideally this would be a band-aid fix until a newer version of Xamarin.Build.Download allows for this situation or newer a version of Xamarin.Firebase.Functions doesn't depend on a preview dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same issue with the `-beta01` suffix, so I downgraded Xamarin.Firebase.Functions to **119.2.0** in order to use the package, which works.
I wonder why Google puts experimental feature dependencies in stable package...